# Cross Domain Request with AngularJS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to do a Cross Domain Request using Angular, but I got the error

> ```
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://machine_name_in_my_network:8082/GetAll. No
> ```
>
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   `resource. Origin 'http://localhost:53379' is therefore not allowed`
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

I saw [here](http://better-inter.net/enabling-cors-in-angular-js/) a solution sample, but doesn't worked for me.

This is a request from my localhost to a machine in my network and should return a JSON.

**Code Snippet**

```
//Controller 
function crmContatosCtrl($scope, apiService) {
    apiService.get('/GetAll').then(function (data) {
       $scope.contatos = data;
    });
```

and then comes to my service

```
function comWebApi_Service($http, $log) {
    return {
        get: function (url, data) {

            //return $http.jsonp(ApiURL + url)
            //    .success(function (data) {
            //        debugger;
            //    })
            //    .error(function (data) {
            //        debugger;
            //    });

            return $http.get(ApiURL + url, data).then(
                function (res) {                
                    return res.data;
                });
        },

    angular
        .module('app')
        .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
            delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        }])
        .service('apiService', comWebApi_Service);
```

Comment: can you show what you see in your network tab... response??

Comment: @harish Appears `This request has no response data available.`, with a Error 500

Comment: You cannot simply enable cors by setting a header on the client side, the server you are making the request to has to have CORS enabled

Comment: can you share what have you tried on server side? how you enabled cors?? cors enabling is server side decision as well...

Comment: @harish we just follow the tutorial, http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html

Comment: @harish Can you show me a sample ? I ask the devolper who develop the WebAPI and her answer was that he just follow these tutorial that I told.

Comment: read [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to enable cors on server

e.g. to init it globally

```
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);
```

read more about it [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)... read section `Scope Rules for [EnableCors]`

Answer (score 1):

This is missing code on the **server** side, not in your browser AngularJS code. You do **not** need either of these lines with recent angularjs builds. These are both based on outdated information (They won't break anything, they are just unnecessary and based on outdated copypasta):

```
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

Your server code needs to add the necessary CORS headers to its HTTP responses, so ask the maintainer to do so or post server side snippets and we can help with that.